# How would someone with medical experience treat a closed fracture of the tibia without proper equipment?

Tags: surgery, bones, bone-fractures, tibia

Let's assume a few people were stranded in the wilderness and didn't have access to proper medical equipment. One suffers a simple, closed fracture of the tibia right between knee and foot joint due to a fall. One of the stranded people is a surgeon and he has to come up with a way of treating that fracture with very limited equipment and tools (basically nothing but a first-aid-kit and anything that's available in the wilderness). How would he approach that and how high would the wounded person's chances of healing without permanent damage be?

Edit: I'm asking this because I'm currently working on a fictional piece in which exactly this is featured. I already found out from a bit of googling that, in such a case, conservative, non-invasive therapy would be the only feasible approach. Would you do this with an improvised orthesis? Or could you fashion some kind of gypsum-based aid if you had access to that? And how would the reduction of the fracture work? Could you even do that without X-Ray or some other imaging technique? How did people fix broken legs before such things came along?
I'd be very grateful for someone who could describe their personal approach at such a procedure in detail, as I'd like to stay as realistic as possible.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: @CareyGregory You're right, I'm sorry. I've become to accustomed to the "soft" SE-boards like writing, literature and academia that I've forgotten how to ask good scientific questions. Will edit promptly.

Comment: Without an x-ray, how does your surgeon know it's a simple closed fracture? Or even a fracture at all?

Comment: Wouldn't that be kind of obvious if the leg had an unnatural bend, but no bleeding occurs? I mean, he probably couldn't tell how complex the fracture was internally, but he should be able to tell that it's a closed tibia fracture, even without X-Ray, no?

Comment: Have you researched this?

Comment: @DLCom Fractures often aren't obvious. There isn't necessarily any deformity, especially with "simple" fractures as you described it, nor do all fractures need to be reduced. These are the kinds of things a little prior research would reveal. You might begin by finding out what an EMT would do since they don't have x-rays either.

Comment: @CareyGregory You know, that was actually a really good tip. I was too stupid to search for EMT stuff instead of state-of-the-art procedures that would only be done in a hospital. What I read on https://www.emsworld.com/article/10321975/fracture-management was pretty much exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help! Please make this an answer so that I can accept it as correct!

Comment: @DLCom You're the one who found the information so you should write the answer. Answering your own question and accepting your own answer is perfectly acceptable on SE.

Comment: And now could you please add something you've learned to your question so it shows some prior research? It has 4 close votes and those votes are justified. One more and your question is toast.